# munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fffbef49d90 in a recursive function

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion

I am new to programming, so even after trying to google this error I couldn't find anything that was either relevant to my project or was simple enough for me to follow.

I have to make a function that reverses a string iteratively, then another function which does so recursively. The iterative function works perfectly fine:

```
string reverse(string str_input) {
    string result = ""; //initialize a blank string to hold reversed string
    for(int i = (str_input.length() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
            result += str_input.substr(i,1); //concatenates the string backwards
    }

    return result;
```

However when I tried to make it recursive, I got an invalid pointer error. I've copied my main I'm using for testing and the other function here:
string reverse_rec(string str_input, string result, int input_length);

```
int main() {

    string str_input = "hello";
    int input_length = (str_input.length() - 1);
    string result = "";

    cout<< reverse_rec(str_input, result, input_length) << endl;

    return 0;

}

string reverse_rec(string str_input, string result, int input_length) {
    if(input_length <= 0) {
            return result;
    } else {
            reverse_rec(str_input, result += str_input.substr(input_length,1), --input_length);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any hints as to what might be causing this error? From what I've read, most of the people got this error when trying to delete things, but I don't seem to be deleting anything in this program...

Note: We have to do this by concatenating substrings and not by using arrays, as we haven't covered arrays in depth yet.

Comment: From what I can tell, this won't work. You're attempting to modify a string in-place. Looking at other implementations, they either use iterators or pointer arithmetic. Consider rethinking your approach.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to return:

```
        reverse_rec(str_input, result += str_input.substr(input_length,1), --input_length);
  ^^^^^
```

Such errors can be easily spotted by the compiler. You should enable warnings.